# How to read dictionary in different manner?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm having one dictionary which key is number and value is one or many lists. I want to read this dictionary so that I can separate key and value.

**Dictionary-**

```
{
 1468332424064000: '[80000,2]',
 1468332423282000: '[30000,6]',
 1468332421081000: '[40000,2]',
 1468332424121000: '[30000,2][40000,2]',
 1468332424014000: '[60000,2]',
 1468332421131000: '[40000,2][30000,6]',
 1468332422921000: '[60000,2]',
 1468332421046000: '[40000,2]',
 1468332422217000: '[40000,2]',
 1468332424921000: '[40000,2]',
 1468332421459000: '[30000,6]',
 1468332422579000: '[60000,2][30000,6]',
 1468332422779000: '[30000,2]',
 1468332424161000: '[70000,6]'
}
```

**Program-Code-**

```
for k,v in latency_obj.d.iteritems():
     li = v.split()
     for l in li:
         print l
```

**Output-**

```
[80000,2]
[30000,6]
[40000,2]
[30000,2][40000,2]
[60000,2]
[40000,2][30000,6]
[60000,2]
[40000,2]
[40000,2]
[40000,2]
[30000,6]
[60000,2][30000,6]
[30000,2]
[70000,6]
```

But I want this two lists as a separate lists so that I can retrieve values of that lists. Any Idea What I'm missing?

Comment: What two lists?

Comment: You want `[60000,2][30000,6]` to be as `[ [60000,2], [30000,6] ]` ?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams- separately I can access values of that list.

Comment: You don't have lists, you have strings.

Comment: Iron Fist- yes I just want to read each n every value of that all list containing available there in value of dictionary.

Comment: `len(li)` is always 1. Please check

Comment: .values() and .keys() return values and keys as list, Is that what you want ?

Comment: @cricket_007- I know. that's the question. How can I retrieve values of that all lists?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you expect your result to look like

```
[80000,2]
[30000,2]
[40000,2]
[60000,2]
[30000,6]
[40000,2]
[30000,6]
[30000,2]
[40000,2]
[40000,2]
[70000,6]
[60000,2]
[30000,6]
[60000,2]
[40000,2]
[40000,2]
[30000,6]
```

I suggest splitting each value on `[`, like so:

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    li = v.split('[')
    for l in li:
        if l:
            print '[' + l
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for key,value in d.items():
    d[key] = eval(value.replace(']','],',1))
```

**output**

```
{1468332421046000: ([40000, 2],),
 1468332421081000: ([40000, 2],),
 1468332421131000: ([40000, 2], [30000, 6]),
 1468332421459000: ([30000, 6],),
 1468332422217000: ([40000, 2],),
 1468332422579000: ([60000, 2], [30000, 6]),
 1468332422779000: ([30000, 2],),
 1468332422921000: ([60000, 2],),
 1468332423282000: ([30000, 6],),
 1468332424014000: ([60000, 2],),
 1468332424064000: ([80000, 2],),
 1468332424121000: ([30000, 2], [40000, 2]),
 1468332424161000: ([70000, 6],),
 1468332424921000: ([40000, 2],)}
```

So you can change the string into tuple and you can access all the values.

You can access the values like this.

```
In [1]: d[1468332421131000]
Out[1]: ([40000, 2], [30000, 6])
In [2]: d[1468332421131000][0]
Out[2]: [40000, 2]
In [3]: d[1468332421131000][1]
Out[3]: [30000, 6]
In [4]: d[1468332421131000][0][1]
Out[4]: 2
```

**Concept :**

`replace(']','],',1)` will replace the first occurance of `]` with `],` and just evaluate with `eval`. And stored the same dictionary itself.

Comment: How I can iterate through that output dictionary so that I can get each n every value of that dictionary. i.e. value of list also like 40000 & 2.

Comment: @kit `[j for i in d.values() for j in i]` use this to make a flat list. And iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the 'lists' i.e. dictionary values that are been discussed here as string, the numbers can be  extracted using regular expressions.

```
>>> import re
>>> lists = '[30000,2][40000,2]'
>>> out_list = re.findall('\d+',lists)
['30000', '2', '40000', '2']  # The elements are actually strings
>>> [eval(n) for n in out_list]
[30000, 2, 40000, 2]  # List containing numbers
```

Hope this is what you are expecting.